# Laravel Database Relationship won't load associated data (edit)

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am trying to make a forum with sections and categories in laravel 5.7. All these sections has multiple categories.

When I build my relationship en try to get the data in the view, I get a error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
'forum_categories.forum_section_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `forum_categories` where `forum_categories`.`forum_section_id` = 1 and `forum_categories`.`forum_section_id` is not null)
```

This is my blade:

```
@foreach($sections as $section) 
                        <h1 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#section{{$section->id}}">{{$section->name}}</h1>
                        <div class="collapse" id="section{{$section->id}}">
                            Dit is sectie
                            @foreach($section->ForumCategory as $forumCategory)
                                {{$forumCategory->id}}
                                @endforeach
                        </div>
 @endforeach
```

My Controller function index():

```
    $sections = ForumSection::all();
    return view('forum.index', compact(['sections']));
```

And this are My models: 
**ForumCategory**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class ForumCategory extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
     'name', 'active', 'position', 'section_id'
  ];
  public function ForumSection() {
     return $this->belongsTo(ForumSection::class, 'section_id');
  }
}
```

**Model ForumSection**:

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ForumSection extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','active', 'position'
    ];
    public function ForumCategory() {
        return $this->hasMany(ForumCategory::class, 'section_id');
    }
}
```

And Last: My 2 database tables:

**ForumSectionsTable**

```
public function up()
    {
            Schema::create('forum_sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->integer('position')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**ForumCategoriesTable**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('forum_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('active');
        $table->integer('section_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('forum_categories', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('forum_sections');
    });
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple... I renamed ForumCategory and ForumSection to Category and Section and the problem was gone... I've learned a lesson ;)

Answer (score 2):

This one should be pretty clear... It's looking for

```
'forum_categories.forum_section_id'
```

as your linking id, but you're using

```
Schema::create('forum_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
  ...
  $table->integer('section_id')->unsigned();
});
```

To solve this, you have a couple options: Override your migration and use `forum_section_id` instead of `section_id`, or add the ID to your relationship:

```
return $this->hasMany(ForumCategory::class, 'section_id');
```

You did that correctly for the `belongsTo` method, but seem to have missed it on the `hasMany` (inverse) method.

Next, use a loop to get a single `id`, as `$seciton->ForumCategory` is a `Collection`, and not a single Model:

```
@foreach($section->ForumCateogry AS $forumCateogry)
Dit is sectie {{ $forumCateogry->id }}
@endforeach
```

That brings up the note on naming conventions; method names are usually "camelCase", so `forumCateogry()` instead of `ForumCateogry()`, and pluralized for methods that return multiple, so `forumCateogries()` instead of `forumCateogry()`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180701/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-lewis-laravel-database-relationship-wont-load-assoc).